# what does "blocks" mean in the context of HDFS ecosystem? is it the same concept in the context of a single hard disk drive?

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

According to [Hortonworks](https://hortonworks.com/apache/hdfs/)

> HDFS has demonstrated production scalability of up to 200 PB of
>   storage and a single cluster of 4500 servers, supporting close to a
>   billion files and blocks.

what does "blocks" mean in this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially yes but the size is very different. A hard drives default block size is 512 bytes but Hadoops default block size is 128 Megabytes.

Hadoop also replicates blocks to maintain integrity of the data.